# Rails - exchange attributes values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called **decoders_contracts** with this attributes:

```
id | decoder_id | contract_id
1       3              31
2       3              31
3       1              31
4       1              31
...
```

I need to exchange the decoder_id this way:

```
id | decoder_id | contract_id
1       1              31
2       1              31
3       3              31
4       3              31
...
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't works:

```
contract_id = params[:contract_id] # 31
dc1 = params[:dc1] # 1
dc2 = params[:dc2] # 3

DecodersContract.where(contract_id: contract_id, decoder_id: dc1).update_all(decoder_id: dc2)
DecodersContract.where(contract_id: contract_id, decoder_id: dc2).update_all(decoder_id: dc1)
```

All decoders_id became **1**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't do it that way.  After the first `where` all the `DecodersContract` have the same value.

Better would be to have an intermediate value,  preferably one that can't occur naturally.

```
DecodersContract.where(contract_id: contract_id, decoder_id: dc1).update_all(decoder_id: 999)
DecodersContract.where(contract_id: contract_id, decoder_id: dc2).update_all(decoder_id: dc1)
DecodersContract.where(contract_id: contract_id, decoder_id: 999).update_all(decoder_id: dc2)
```